# How to upload a django file in memory to S3

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a fil to S3 without using a custom backend. This is what I have so far:

```
conn=boto.connect_s3(settings.AWS_KEY, settings.AWS_SECRET)
bucket=conn.get_bucket(settings.AWS_BUCKET)
k = Key(bucket)

filename = f.name
keyname = str(int(uuid.uuid4()))[:10] + filename
k.key = keyname
k.set_contents_from_filename(f)
url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/.../" + keyname
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /qc/86/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found
```

How would I correctly upload a file from `request['FILES']` to s3 without using a custom storage backend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced a similar issue a while back instead of using `set_contents_from_filename(f)` try `k.set_contents_from_string(f.read())`

I did the same thing in this project here: https://github.com/buddylindsey/developerrage/blob/master/developerrage/comic/views.py

Comment: Great, this was my issue also. Thanks.

Comment: how to do it is boto3?

Comment: How to do it with boto3?